# Pytorch tensor dimension multiplication

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch

I'm trying to implement the grad-camm algorithm:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02391.pdf

My arguments are:

activations: Tensor with shape `torch.Size([1, 512, 14, 14])`

alpha values : Tensor with shape `torch.Size([512])`

I want to multiply each activation (in dimension index 1 (sized 512)) in each corresponding alpha value: for example if the i'th index out of the 512 in the activation is 4 and the i'th alpha value is 5, then my new i'th activation would be 20.

The shape of the output should be torch.Size([1, 512, 14, 14])

Comment: Thank you for undeleting this post (you can delete the new one now..). Welcome to Stack Overflow John. If you feel an answer doesn't fit your question, you shouldn't just delete the whole thing to create an exact same replica. It's quite rude for those who have spent time answering! Please edit your question if the answer below isn't right for you.

Comment: I'll try to edit it now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you show me the desired output when using `x` and `y` from below (the aragement from *0* to *15*).

Comment: We go over each feature map (each channel) of the extracted features and multiply it by the alpha calculated. The feature maps are the numbers conatined in activations tensor in index 1 (sized 512) so as I understand from the algorithm we should take each of these and multiple them by the corresponding scalar on alpha values.

Comment: I'm starting to think I got it wrong and you got it right, but your code didn't even compile for me. How can I make it work?
I have two tensors as I've said, x (4 dimensions) and y (1 dimension) and the output should also be 4 dimensions. Thanks!

Comment: The way I see it there is a single batch element (`dim=0`) with 512 channels (`dim=1`) of size `height=14` (`dim=2`) and `width=14` (`dim=3`).

Comment: Good. What error are you getting when running `x*y[None, :, None, None]`?

Comment: This one seems to work!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helped! Don't forget to mark the answer below as correct (by clicking on the green check mark).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the desired output is of shape `(1, 512, 14, 14)`.

You can achieve this with `torch.einsum`:

```
torch.einsum('nchw,c->nchw', x, y)
```

Or with a simple dot product, but you will first need to add a couple of additional dimensions on `y`:

```
x*y[None, :, None, None]
```

---

Here's an example with `x.shape = (1, 4, 2, 2)` and `y = (4,)`:

```
>>> x = torch.arange(16).reshape(1, 4, 2, 2)
tensor([[[[ 0,  1],
          [ 2,  3]],

         [[ 4,  5],
          [ 6,  7]],

         [[ 8,  9],
          [10, 11]],

         [[12, 13],
          [14, 15]]]])

>>> y = torch.arange(1, 5)
tensor([1, 2, 3, 4])

>>> x*y[None, :, None, None]
tensor([[[[ 0,  1],
          [ 2,  3]],

         [[ 8, 10],
          [12, 14]],

         [[24, 27],
          [30, 33]],

         [[48, 52],
          [56, 60]]]])
```

Comment: Yeah but if that is my input (x,y,z,w) only y dimension should be multiplied if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: No, all channels will be multiplied by the alpha value from the `y` tensor. Look at the result channel *3*: `[[ 8,  9], [10, 11]]` multiplied by *3* gives `[[24, 27], [30, 33]]`.